# Getting a 'Could Not Find Driver' message with new domain name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am using a php framework and am successfully using it with the first website I created. I bought a new domain and am working on my second site. The php framework I have is basically for registering/signing in with a lot of other things, but that's the core essentials behind it. What I am trying to do is create my new site with the same framework as it will be a member based site. For some reason though I am getting these errors:

> Warning: `PDO::__construct()` expects parameter 2 to be string, array
>   given in `/home4/pfarley1/public_html/example.com/classes/DB.php` on
>   line 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function `prepare()` on a non-object in
>   `/home4/pfarley1/public_html/example.com/classes/DB.php` on line 27

like 13:

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
```

line 27:

```
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
```

I have a core/init file that pulls my db/host credentials and that has the correct information in it.

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysqli' => array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'sfd'
),
```

I have tried changing line 13 to mysqli for everything by doing this:

```
    $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysqli:host=' . Config::get('mysqli/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysqli/db'), Config::get('mysqli/username'), Config::get('mysqli/password'));
```

When I do that, I get the 'Could not find driver' error.

What am I doing wrong? This exact same code works for my other website I have that is on the same host??

Comment: where are lines 1 to 100 documented here ? You found yourself in a forum like thing, talking to others

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: show us the code so we can see how scrambled it is. It is not like your reputation is 1

Comment: please use the PDO constructor in try{} catch(){} use
 `try {
     $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysqli:host=' . Config::get('mysqli/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysqli/db'), Config::get('mysqli/username'), Config::get('mysqli/password'));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}` and let know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO and MySqli are mutually exclusive. They do similar things and cannot be used together.

To use PDO (my strong recommendation), change references from MySqli to MySQL

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'sfd'
),
```

Here is an in depth comparison between the two - [PDO vs MySQLi](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use firstly provided `$this->_pdo`, change `mysqli` in your config to `mysql`.